# How to disable/change the function of the share button while ar quicklook package for react-native?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, share-button

While using the sample project to test AR Quicklook, the share button in AR Quicklook shares the entire 3D model as a file, is there any way in which model sharing can be stopped or altered?

The sample code for the same is in :
https://github.com/tgdevjs/rn-ar-quicklook

Tried to add canonical website for the same but I couldn't figure out how.I tried to alter the RNFileViewerManager.m    file, under react-native-file-viewer folder inside node_modules, but couldn't come up with any solution.